# Wrong fire date UILocalNotification - fire date is one hour ahead

Tags: ios, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to set a UILocalNotification to go off at a certain time. The app deals with restaurant bookings. If a booking is made and the appointment is greater than 2 hours from now, then I want to show the notification 2 hours before it. If it is greater than 1 hour then I was to show it 1 hour before hand, else I want to show it 15 mins before hand. The dificulty Im having is that my UILocalNotification fire time is wrong by `+ 1 hour`. Below is the code used:

```
[self setLocalNotificationWithAlertBody:@"Alert Body goes here" AndWithBookingDateString:@"2015-09-07 19:45:00"];//the booking time



-(void)setLocalNotificationWithAlertBody:(NSString *)body AndWithBookingDateString:(NSString *)dateString{

    NSLog(@"Date String %@",dateString);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"Date from String %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

    [self setLocalNotificationWithAlertBody:body AndWithBookingDate:dateFromString];
}



 -(void)setLocalNotificationWithAlertBody: (NSString *) body AndWithBookingDate: (NSDate *)date{

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:currentDate
                                             toDate:date
                                            options:0];


    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];


    if (components.hour>=2) {//remind the user 2 hours before hand if booking is made greater than 2 hours


        NSTimeInterval secondsPerHour = (60 * 60)*2;//two hours before appointment
        NSDate *givenDate = date; // what you have already
        NSDate *earlierDate = [givenDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsPerHour];
         NSLog(@"\n\n Greater than 2 hours %@ \n\n",earlierDate);
        localNotification.fireDate=earlierDate;
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",body,[self getDeviceShortDateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date] WithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"]];
    }
    else if (components.hour>1) {

        NSTimeInterval secondsPerHour = 60 * 60;
        NSDate *givenDate = date; // what you have already
        NSDate *earlierDate = [givenDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsPerHour];
        NSLog(@"\n\n Greater than an hour %@ \n\n",earlierDate);
        localNotification.fireDate=earlierDate;
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",body,[self getDeviceShortDateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date] WithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"]];

    }
    else{


        NSTimeInterval secondsPer15mins = 15 * 60;
        NSDate *givenDate = date; // what you have already
        NSDate *earlierDate = [givenDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsPer15mins];
         NSLog(@"\n\n Less than one hour %@ \n",earlierDate);


        localNotification.fireDate=earlierDate;
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",body,[self getDeviceShortDateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date] WithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"]];


    }


    localNotification.userInfo = @{@"key" : body};
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    NSLog(@"Fire date %@",localNotification.fireDate);

    NSLog(@"Notification--->: %@", localNotification);


}


  -(NSString *)getDeviceShortDateFromString: (NSString *) date WithFormat: (NSString *)format{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];

    NSDate * tempDate =[dateFormatter dateFromString: date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];
    if (tempDate == nil) {
        return @" ";
    }

    return [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:tempDate];

}
```

The fire date is logging as:

```
Fire date 2015-09-07 17:45:00 +0000
```

But the local notification is wrong:

```
Notification--->: <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x174178300>{fire date = Monday 7 September 2015 18:45:00 Irish Summer Time, time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday 7 September 2015 18:45:00 Irish Summer Time, user info = {
key = "Alert Body Goes here";
}}
```

The appointment was booked greater than 2 hours so the notification should be going off at 5:45 but it doesnt go off until 6:45. Any help is greatly appreciated.

"Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope" :)

Comment: If this is for a users own time zone why isn't it set to system time zone? If I'm a user using that app and I schedule a reservation 2 hours from now, it should be two hours from now from my respective time zone correct? Unless your trying to eat someone with a GMT time zones

Comment: @soulshined well spotted, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scaleable apps that rely on location specific results, ensure that your location specific properties always point to the users relative location. In your case, you just overlooked a simple setting:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

For you, this is +1 hour, but for others it will vary some will be ahead and some will be behind, because your basing the fireDate on GMT's time.

I would simply alter this to be `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]`